# What is Quantum Phase Estimation in Shor's Algorithm?

Tags: shors-algorithm, quantum-phase-estimation, phase-kickback

While I'm studying Algorithm, I couldn't understand what Quantum Phase Estimation is. And I heard there is relation between Phase-Kickback and Quantum Phase Estimation. I wonder what it is. Also, I'm not sure what this is and how it works within the algorithm. I would like to learn from the mathematical point of view and the conceptual part.

Answer (score 4):

Phase estimation is the process by which you are given a controlled-$U$ unitary, and a state that you are promised is an eigenvector of $U$ with eigenvalue $e^{2\pi ix/2^t}$, then you can use a $t$-qubit register to affect the change
$$
|0\rangle^{\otimes t}|u\rangle\mapsto|y\rangle|u\rangle.
$$
If $x$ is in integer, then the outcome is guaranteed to be $y=x$. If $x$ is not an integer, $y$ is, with high probability, the closest integer to $x$.

The phase-kickback is the way that we get something, apparently on the second register (i.e. the $|u\rangle$ being acted upon by $U$) to change the first register. In effect, this is making use of the difference between global phase (as it would be for $U$) and relative phase in a superposition (which is what you actually get when you use controlled-$U$).

Before I go into the detailed mathematics, what have you read so far (as this is standard in all texts)? What is it you don't understand?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to learn more generally about phase estimation, the book I am helping write has a whole chapter on it, [Learn Quantum Computing with Python and Q#](https://www.manning.com/books/learn-quantum-computing-with-python-and-q-sharp) (chapter 8). 
Ping me here or via [email](https://www.sckaiser.com) and I can get you a discount code!